# Wrong output with OpenCV Distance Transform

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to find the Distance Transform for each pixels of a binary image, using OpenCV library for C. According to the rule of DT, the value of each zero (black) pixels should be 0. And that of 255 (white) pixels should be the shortest distance to a zero (black) pixel, after applying Distance transform.

I post the code here.

```
IplImage *im = cvLoadImage("black_white.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
IplImage *tmp = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im), 32, 1);
cvThreshold(im, im, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
//cvSaveImage("out.jpg", im);
cvDistTransform(im, tmp, CV_DIST_L1, 3, 0, 0 );
d = (uchar*)tmp->imageData;
da = (uchar*)im->imageData;

for(i=0;i<tmp->height;i++)
                          for(j=0;j<tmp->width;j++)
                          {
                                                   //if((int)da[i*im->widthStep + j] == 255)
                                                   fprintf(f, "pixel value = %d DT = %d\n", (int)da[i*im->widthStep + j], (int)d[i*tmp->widthStep + j]);
                          }
                          cvShowImage("H", tmp);
                          cvWaitKey(0);
                          cvDestroyWindow("H");
fclose(f);
```

I write the pixels values along with their DT values to a file. As it turns out, some of the 0 pixels have DT values like 65, 128 etc. ie they are not 0. Moreover, I also have some white pixels that have DT values as 0 (which I guess, souldn't happen as it should be atleast 1).

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the resolution of you image?A suggestion..try playing with the window size...make the window size bigger and check...

Comment: The resolution ranges from around 600X800 to 1600X1200. But will that affect the result of DT ?

Comment: Here your window is 3x3....try a bigger window...10x10 or 20x20...n plz let us know wether you get some improvement in results..

Comment: The only masks possible are 3X3 or 5X5. Even if I use IplConvKernel, only values 3 (3X3), 5 (5X5) can be used. Is it even possible to construct bigger windows.

Comment: Sorry, guess I was wrong. You can construct a bigger window. I created a window of size 10X10 but I couldn't use that in the cvDistTrans function. Says it takes only windows (mask) of size 3 or 5 or 0.

Comment: can u upload your test image?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22704/discussion-between-bluechill-and-rotating-image)

Comment: Where is the image? come to chat...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because of `CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV` which inverts your image. So the areas you expect to be white are in fact black for DT.

Of cause, inverting the image may be your intention. Display the image `im` and compare with `tmp` for verification